# Connect datasource with proxy

Tags: java, tomcat, druid

For some reason, I have to connect mysql with socks proxy during the development, and the program uses druid as datasource.
I've tried to add vm option `-Dhttp.proxyHost=host -Dhttp.proxyPort=port` in idea's run/debug configurations, and set `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS  -Dhttp.proxyHost=host -Dhttp.proxyPort=port"` in catalina.sh, but neither of them works.
I wonder is there any way to connect datasource while using proxy? Thanks for your helping!

Comment: I've solved this problem with setting a SSH port forwarding.
But configuring tomcat/datasource to connect through proxy is still unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Try `-DsocksProxyHost=socks.example.com - DsocksProxyPort=1080`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. All these methods I've tried show me the result that druid didn't connect database through the proxy as expected.